# Unexpected result in String Comparison In java?

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="yes";
        String s2="yes";

        System.out.println("-------The result is-----"+ s1==s2);
        System.out.println("-------The result is-----"+ (s1==s2));    
    }
}
```

Why the above code produce the output
 "false"
-------The result is-----true

Comment: You'll find a lot of stuff when you google this out. If you want to compare strings, use 'equals' or 'equalsIgnoreCase'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, read the question carefully

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should not be comparing strings with `==`, but with `equals()`.

There's also the issue of operator precedence. This:

```
"-------The result is-----"+ s1==s2
```

is the same as:

```
("-------The result is-----"+ s1) == s2
```

because `+` has higher precedence than `==`.

Answer (score 0):

when you are comparing strings you should change up `==` to be `.equals()` due to the fact that `.equals()` compares the contents of the strings to each other or is used to compare objects. `==` checks for reference equality or is used to compare primitives. I changed your code below:

```
System.out.println("-------The result is-----"+ (s1.equals(s2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the references of `s1` and `s2`, and since you defined them separately, they don't have the same references. To compare the strings, please use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

```
'+' > '=='
```

so

`"-------The result is-----"+ s1==s2`  becomes

`("-------The result is-----"+ s1)==s2` and hence false.